# Porque el Textbox no se muestra?

Tags: python, tkinter

mi programa se niega a mostrar el textbox incluso usando `.pack`

```
from tkinter import *

#WINDOW
Root = Tk()
#SETTINGS
Root.title('URANIUM CODE')
Root.geometry('600x625')
Root.minsize(width=600, height=625)
Root.config(bg='#2b2b2b')

#MIDDLE
Separator = Label(bg='#38e300',text='',width=1,height=625)
Separator.place(x=300,y=1)
Separator.pack()

#CODEBOX1
CBOX1 = Text(Root,bg='#575757',font=('Courier',12),undo=True)
CBOX1.config(highlightthickness=0)
CBOX1.pack(expand=True,side=LEFT,fill=BOTH)




Root.mainloop()
```

probé usando `.place` y así si se muestra pero necesito poner un textbox del lado derecho y otro del izquierdo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Su código está mal organizado, usted está sobreponiendo el control del Label o `tk.Label()` sobre el control del cuadro de texto o `tk.Text()`, evite utilizar comodín para importar la librería Tkinter, esto se cataloga como una mala práctica de programación.

**La solución quedaría así:**

```
import tkinter as tk

#WINDOW
Root = tk.Tk()
#SETTINGS
Root.title('URANIUM CODE')
Root.geometry('600x625')
Root.minsize(width=600, height=625)
Root.config(bg='#2b2b2b')

#CODEBOX1
CBOX1 = tk.Text(Root,bg='#575757',font=('Courier',12),undo=True)
CBOX1.config(highlightthickness=0)
CBOX1.pack(expand=True,side='left',fill='both')

#MIDDLE
Separator = tk.Label(bg='#38e300',text='',width=1,height=625)
Separator.place(x=300,y=1)
Separator.pack()


Root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sabes como podría dividir la ventana en 2 me refiero a un textbox a la derecha otro a la izquierda y en el medio un label con BG verde como separador de textboxs llevo varias horas intentando poner uno a la derecha y otro a la izquierda pero no he podido sabes como puedo arreglaro